# HTML5 from validation pattern not working for string start with some specific chars

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am trying to validate a text field content should start with specific chars like *GTM.......* in the below example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="myText" required pattern="/^GTM/"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Sumit"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/jehuyuresa/edit?html,console,output)

Comment: That's fantastic, and what's your question?

Comment: @RubenSerrate, his question is why the regex he made is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to start the pattern with `^`.

Just `GTM.*` will do:

You need the `.*` saying that **GTM** can be followed by `0` or more characters.

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="myText" required pattern='GTM.*'/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: *"content should start with specific chars"* I think `^` is required

Comment: I did many tests. Look at this [w3schools link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) on the last example

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `/` from your pattern and add `.*`

```
 <input type="text" id="myText" required pattern="^GTM.*"/>
```